# BroadcastReceiver not working : Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am implementing a sample code for BroadcastReceiver, where it will start from a specific time, but there is something problem in my code and its not working..

Here is my code:

In Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"), Locale.US);
        cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 31);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 10);

        Intent intent = new Intent(HelloAlarmManagerActivity.this, ScheduleHandler.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(HelloAlarmManagerActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 2*10, pIntent);
        Toast.makeText(HelloAlarmManagerActivity.this, "Alarm seted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

and my BrodcastReceiver class is as :

```
public class ScheduleHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

After running this application, I am getting only first toast message. It means broadcast receiver not getting called.

Is there any problem in my code?

Comment: just an idea: can it be that if you call cal.add(Calendar.Month, 10) that you added 10 Month to NOW? Try to determine what a value is cal.getTimeInMillis. You could also try alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis + 1000, 2*10, pIntent); to see if its a simple timing mistake

Comment: @Rafael T  cal.add(Calendar.Month, 10) is this mean I am adding 10 months from now? Ohhh I thought it should be of Oct then I added 10 (for Oct).... so what should be for current month?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Repeat interval is 20 (2*10) milliseconds. I have no Idea how phones would react to that, but It might be the cause of your problem